# Can I transit through the USA as citizen of a Schengen State during COVID-19?

Tags: usa, schengen, transit, covid-19

I'm planning on traveling to Nicaragua and most flights are transferring through the United States, but as I have read citizens of the Schengen States can't enter the US unless they have been out of the restricted countries for 14 days. Does this count for transitting too?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For accuracy for future readers, the ban does not apply just to citizens of Schengen States, but to anyone who has been there in the last 14 days, except US citizens and permanent residents, their spouses, and a few other limited exemptions.

Comment: @jcaron ("anyone who has been there" -> Including transit)

Comment: Not the question asked, so just a comment:  your best bet is probably via Mexico City.  I believe that AeroMexico is still operating regular flights to a few European cities (though flights are not necessarily daily), and Mexico has not imposed significant travel restrictions.

Comment: There is no COVID-19 ban on "citizens of Schengen states" or citizens of any other country. The ban you are referring to is about people who have been physically present in certain countries, regardless of citizenship. Citizens of Schengen Area states are not subject to the ban if they have not been to the Schengen Area (or one of the other banned countries) in the last 14 days.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this count for transiting too?

Yes, see https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> US for details (depends on where one comes from, visa, spouse, kids, etc.).

> Published 27.08.2020
>
> 1. Passengers who have transited or have been in Austria, Belgium, Brazil, China (People's Rep.), Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland,
>    France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Iran, Ireland (Rep.),
>    Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta,
>    Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain,
>    Sweden, Switzerland or in the United Kingdom (excluding overseas
>    territories outside of Europe), in the past 14 days are **not allowed to
>    enter and transit.**
>
> This does not apply to:
>
> - nationals and permanent residents of the USA;
> - spouses of nationals and of permanent residents of the USA;
> - parents/legal guardians of an unmarried and younger than 21 years national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - the unmarried and younger than 21 years brother or sister of a national or permanent resident of the USA, who is unmarried and
>   younger than 21 years;
> - the child/foster child/ward of a national or permanent resident of the USA;
> - passengers with the following visas: A-1, A-2, C-1, C-1/D, C-2, C-3, CR-1, CR-2, D, E-1 (as an employee of TECRO or TECO or the employee's
>   immediate family members), G-1, G-2, G-3, G-4, IR-1, IR-4, IH-4,
>   NATO-1 through NATO-4, or NATO-6 visa;
> - members of the U.S. Armed Forces, spouses, and children of members of the U.S. Armed Forces;
> - passengers with evidence of traveling at the invitation of the USA government for a purpose related to the containment/mitigation of the
>   Coronavirus (COVID-19);
> - passengers with documents issued by the U.S. Department of Homeland Security, U.S. Customs and Border Protection, or U.S. Department of
>   State indicating that the passenger is exempt from the restriction;
> - B1 crew crewmembers that are engaged in lightering, Outer Continental Shelf (OCS) activity, wind farm activity, private air/sea
>   crew and other similar crewmember actives;
> - students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents, if they arrive from or have been in Ireland (Rep.), United Kingdom or
>   Schengen Member States in the past 14 days.

Comment: Franck, OP wants to transit in the USA, can you please include that these rules and exemptions are also for those who do not want to leave the airport?

Comment: There is no airside transit in the USA. Everyone goes through immigration/customs and ends up landside, including transit passengers. Though I find it a bit strange that they exempt transit visa holders, but not visa-exempt people who wish to transit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The actual proclamation (e.g. [the one for the Schengen Area](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/03/16/2020-05578/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of), but the ones for Mainland China, Iran, UK/Ireland, and Brazil are similar) only exempt people traveling on C-1, D, or C-1/D visas "as a crewmember", not people on C-1 visas in general. The IATA info above is inaccurate.